# Keycloak - Registration Page - Custom Attributes

Tags: java, keycloak

I have created a custom theme on keycloak.
I have an input where i want the user to select his country of birth.

I want the options of this select to not be harcoded in the ftl file. Is there a way to override the keycloak registration provider to add my custom attribute where i would store the countries ?

Note : I am using keycloak v19

Thanks

I have already tried to override the "FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider" without success.
I made a custom js file to update my country input but this is not a good way to do it since the end goal is to get the list of the country from an API and i dont want to call the API using js.